# Copy an image to a bigger image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to copy a sub image to a bigger image. Say I have image1 and image2 where image2 has size 600x300 and image1 has size 200x100. I want to copy image1 on to image2, while the rest of image2 remains. I have tried something like this -

```
`back_img = zeros(round(boundary_y),round(boundary_x),3);
back_img = back_img(:,:,:);

[src_y, src_x,~] = size(img1);
back_img(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3) = img1(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3);
figure; imshow(back_img);`
```

I have a black background on top of which I want to paste my image. I'm getting a white box where my image has to be there as my result. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem: `back_img` is of class `double` and `img1` is of class `uint8`.
Show image of class `double` displays all pixels above `1` as white pixels.
In `uint8` class, pixel range is [0, 255], when 255 is white.

Following code: `back_img(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3) = img1(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3);`, place the `uint8` matrix in matrix of class (type) `double`.
In this case, Matlab rule is casting `uint8` elements to `double`.
Using `imshow(back_img)` when `back_img` is `double`, applies pixels range [0, 1] (0 is black, and 1 is white).
Pixels above 1 are also white.
Almost all pixels of original `uint8` image are 1 or above, so displyead as white pixels after converting to double.

Solution: Create the zero matrix in the same class as `img1` (class `uint8` in your case).

Check the following code sample:

```
%Prepeare 200x200 image for the example:
img1 = imresize(imread('peppers.png'), [200, 200]);

boundary_x = 600;
boundary_y = 600;

%back_img = zeros(round(boundary_y),round(boundary_x),3);
%back_img = back_img(:,:,:); %Do nothing...

%Create 600x600x3 zeros matrix in smae class of img1 (in case img1 is
%uint8, class of back_img is uint8 instead of double.
back_img = zeros(round(boundary_y),round(boundary_x),3, class(img1));

[src_y, src_x, ~] = size(img1);
back_img(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3) = img1(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3);
figure; imshow(back_img);
```

Result:
[image]

Result of original code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is the zeros in the background image were doubles, converting them into integers (uint8)  will fix it.

Comment: Converting it into... what?

Answer (score -1):

Many confusing things here, but I think the core problem is

```
back_img(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3) = img1(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3);
```

Do instead

```
back_img(1:src_y, 1:src_x,1:3) = img1;
```

An easier way to achieve black padding is:

```
padarray(A,padsize,padval,direction)
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not fix the issue.